# Reverse of Stemming

Tags: r, snowball

Is there any way in R to reverse process of stemming? I have some russian keywords. I want to find out all the possible roots of the words.

```
library(SnowballC)
wordStem('выявлениа', language = "ru")
wordStem('выявления', language = "ru")
```

It returns `выявлени`. I want to input `выявления` and program should return '`выявлениа`' and '`выявления`'

Comment: The tm package has stemCompletion. It will find the most frequently used word for the root. I am not sure about support for Russian. I know tm supports Russian for its stopwords so maybe look into the stemCompletion language support as well. Also, are you sure you want to reverse stemming? You say in your question you want to find all possible roots; this isnt the reverse of stemming, this IS stemming.

Comment: Maybe lemmatization?  Though this is not the reverse of stemming